# iOS6 NSMutableAttributedString addAttribute:value:range: not working

Tags: objective-c, ios6, xcode4.5, nsattributedstring

My environment: Xcode 4.5.2, iOS 6.0 SDK

At first, I made a simple project with UITextView and Attribuded String by using IB.
[image]
Then, run iOS Simulator, works fine.
[image]

Second, I tried to using attributes by cording. The code is like this.

ViewController.h:

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextView *textView;
```

ViewController.m:

```
[super viewDidLoad];

UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:14.0f];
NSMutableDictionary *attrsDictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObject:font forKey:NSFontAttributeName];

NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSParagraphStyle defaultParagraphStyle] mutableCopy];
[attrsDictionary setObject:paragraphStyle forKey:NSParagraphStyleAttributeName];

NSString *text = @"In iOS 6 and later, this class supports multiple text styles through use of the attributedText property.";

NSMutableAttributedString *attributedText = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:text attributes:attrsDictionary];

NSRange range = NSMakeRange(3, 5); // range of "iOS 6"
[attributedText addAttribute:NSForegroundColorAttributeName value:[UIColor colorWithRed:0.262745 green:0.262745 blue:0.262745 alpha:1] range:range];

self.textView.attributedText = attributedText;
```

The result was not working correctly.
[image]

So, I tried to get log.

```
NSLog(@"%@", self.textView.attributedText);

In {
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x716eef0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0 0 0 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
}iOS 6{
    NSColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.262745 0.262745 0.262745 1";
    NSFont = "<UICFFont: 0x716eef0> font-family: \".Helvetica NeueUI\"; font-weight: normal; font-style: normal; font-size: 14px";
    NSKern = 0;
    NSParagraphStyle = "Alignment 4, LineSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacing 0, ParagraphSpacingBefore 0, HeadIndent 0, TailIndent 0, FirstLineHeadIndent 0, LineHeight 0/0, LineHeightMultiple 0, LineBreakMode 0, Tabs (\n), DefaultTabInterval 36, Blocks (null), Lists (null), BaseWritingDirection 0, HyphenationFactor 0, TighteningFactor 0, HeaderLevel 0";
    NSStrokeColor = "UIDeviceRGBColorSpace 0.262745 0.262745 0.262745 1";
    NSStrokeWidth = 0;
} and later, this class supports multiple text styles through use of the attributedText property.
...
```

It seems to addAttribute: method works fine. But not display... Why?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to call setNeedsDisplay on your textview?

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you are confusing the way storyboard works... you are setting the attributed text in storyboard and then trying to change in it code. In my experience... you do one or the other. I have a form sheet that I set up in Storyboard with Attributed text and it works just as it should on both the simulator and the app. BUT, I don't attempt to override what I've already done in storyboard. If you create something in storyboard, it's done.